# Start a node app from another node app run inside docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, pm2

I have a node app exposes a REST API. When it receives a http request, it starts another/different node app, let's call it 'service app'.

The REST app runs inside a container and the easiest way to start the service app is to just call child_process.exec (we just pm2 though) but then they run inside the same container. If REST app gets multiple requests this one container solution just won't scale.

So is it possible that the REST app can start the service app running inside its own container? If yes how to do that?

Someone also suggested me to run my REST app in docker swarm so when it gets the request it just starts another docker service for the service app. But I have no idea how to do that or even it is possible?

I am new to docker, any advice is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can control docker from inside of container by for example bind mounting /var/run/docker.sock file into container itself (-v flag to docker run). But be very careful, if someone will gain access to it, it will be more or less equal to giving him root access to the machine. Safest way would be to create 2nd REST app that runs in separate container and can start new containers when asked. Then you could just invoke it from 1st app and be sure that it will start only container with your app and nothing else.